# jquery - passar variavel de uma pagina para outra

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

bom, tenho esse cenario... meu index.html chama uma outra pagina (home.html) e existem duas variaveis na index que quero pegar em home para tomar minhas decisoes...

codigo da index.

```
    $("a[data-type]").on('click',function(){
    var _nome = $(this).attr('id')
        _tipo = $(this).attr('data-type')
        dados = {"nome": _nome, "tipo": _tipo};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'home.html',
        data : dados,
        success:function(data){
            $('#conteudo').html(data);
        }
    });
})
```

como consigo pegar as propriedades nome e tipo la na home?

Comment: Você deseja obter esses valores via JavaScript mesmo? Porque se for, acredito não ser possível, pois a página `home.html` não será carregada no navegador e, assim, o JS deste arquivo não é executado.

Comment: na realidade estou imbutindo essa pagina dentro de uma div na minha index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie cookies para passar a variável para a outra pagina, com esta função fica mais fácil de cria-lós:

```
function setCookie(name, value, duration) {
        var cookie = name + "=" + escape(value);
        document.cookie = cookie;
}
```

Para utilizar esta função basta:

```
setCookie("nome_cookie", "Valor_cookie");
```

E esta outra função serve para pega o cookie:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookies = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = cookies.indexOf("; " + prefix);

    if (begin == -1) {

        begin = cookies.indexOf(prefix);

        if (begin != 0) {
            return null;
        }

    } else {
        begin += 2;
    }

    var end = cookies.indexOf(";", begin);

    if (end == -1) {
        end = cookies.length;                        
    }

    return unescape(cookies.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
```

Para utilizar é simples:

```
var nome_cookie = getCookie("nome_cookie");
```

Comment: obrigado wictor... resolveu!!!!